# svg and % height messing up the layout in several broswers

Tags: html, css, svg, css-position

So far I have a site that is displays perfectly in google chrome however on other browsers such as IE, Firefox and Safari the site layout and images get really distorted. The site's original structure should go like this: a colored section covering the entire screen with an svg image in the cneter, a white section covering the entire screen then repeated about 4 times. On internet explorer and firefox however, the image enlarges to take up the whole screen and the colored section starts to take up more than the entire sceen. On safari the layout display fine but my svg images displays in weird proportions that are either too stretched or too small. That may be confusing so I've included a jfiddle and my code down below. I know I've got a weird problem and I think most of it is due to how I set up ym svg but I can't find the solution. Any help is appreciated thanks!

Jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hC2nX/

Html:

```
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div id="headerContent">
            <a href="#"><img src="images/logo-12.svg" width="155px" height="70px"/></a>
            <div id="navLinks">
                <nav id="list">
                    <div id="homeLink" style="background-color:#ff837b;" class="link"><a href="#" class="listLink">Home</a></div>
                    <div id="storyLink" class="link"><a href="#" class="listLink">Story</a></div>
                    <div id="workLink" class="link"><a href="#" class="listLink">Work</a></div>
                    <div id="contactLink" class="link"><a href="#" class="listLink">Contact</a></div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>   
    </div>

        <div id="induoIntro" class="divide">
            <div class="graphic" style="background-color:#ff837b">
                <p><img src="images/WAInduo-02.svg" style="width:50%; height:85%;" /></p>
            </div>

            <div class="textBody">
                 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque ut posuere mauris. Nulla faucibus consectetur mi, nec luctus eros vulputate non. Cras id suscipit metus  </p>   
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="designers" class="divide">                 
            <div class="graphic" style="background-color:#FFB37B">
                <p><img src="images/WAdesign-03.svg" style="width:50%; height:85%;" /></p>
            </div>

            <div class="textBody">
                 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque ut posuere mauris. Nulla faucibus consectetur mi, nec luctus eros vulputate non. Cras id suscipit metus </p>   
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="developers" class="divide">
            <div class="graphic" style="background-color:#CEE28F">
                <p><img src="images/WAdevelop-04.svg" style="width:50%; height:85%;" /></p>
            </div>

            <div class="textBody">
                 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque ut posuere mauris. Nulla faucibus consectetur mi, nec luctus eros vulputate non. Cras id suscipit metus </p>   
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="directors" class="divide">
            <div class="graphic" style="background-color:#C195DA">
                <p><img src="images/WAdirect-05.svg" style="width:50%; height:85%;" /></p>
            </div>

            <div class="textBody">
                 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque ut posuere mauris. Nulla faucibus consectetur mi, nec luctus eros vulputate non. Cras id suscipit metus </p>   
            </div>
        </div>

    <div id="footer">

    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
html {
    height:100%
}

body {
    background-color:#f4f4f4;
    height:100%
}


#header {
    position:absolute;
    height:70px;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#fff;
}

#headerContent {
    width:80%;
    margin:auto;
}

#list {
    position:relative;
    font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
    font-weight:300;
    color: #474747;
    top:-73px;
    float:right;
}

#list a {
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:18px;
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    text-align: center; 
    line-height: 70px;
    display:block;
}

#list a:visited {
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:18px;
    width:70px;
}

.link {
    display:inline-block;
    -webkit-transition: background .8s;
    -moz-transition: background .8s;
    -ms-transition: background .8s;
    -o-transition: background .8s;
    transition: background .8s;
}

#homeLink:hover {
    background-color:#ff837b;
}

#storyLink:hover {
    background-color:#FFB37B;
}

#workLink:hover {
    background-color:#CEE28F;

}

#contactLink:hover {
    background-color:#C195DA;
}
#wrap {
    height:100%;
}

.divide {
    height:200%;
}

.graphic {
    display:table; 
    height:50%;
    width:100%;

}

.graphic p {
    display: table-cell; 
    vertical-align: middle; 
    text-align: center; 
}

.textBody {
    display:table; 
    height:50%;
    width:85%;
    margin:auto;
}

.textBody p {
    display: table-cell; 
    vertical-align: middle; 
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
    font-size:45px;
    margin:auto;
}

#footer {
    height:70px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#252a33;
}
```

Comment: The links to SVG files are unfortunately broken. Can you by any chance fix one of them?

Comment: @eithedog unfortunately I can not upload the svg's somewhere else right now, but the problem remains the same even with broken svgs

Comment: I think that the problem lies with `style="width:50%; height:85%;"` on img - without them (http://jsfiddle.net/hC2nX/2/) the images don't push text outside their own containers and the behavior is consistent between the browsers. Is this what you're after? If the image needs to be x of the height/width of the container - you need to apply `max-height`, `max-width`: http://jsfiddle.net/PG4c7/1/

Comment: Ghh... this is when I edit stuff in console and not in the fiddle.. Sorry - proper link here: http://jsfiddle.net/PG4c7/2/

Comment: @eithedog I've tried removing that at first and while it fixes the issue, my svg won't be able to auto-scale based on the browsers height. Is there a way to allow my svg iamges to scale it's self based on the users screen as well? Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: Sorry - I think I misunderstood you. If you want the images to be resized non-uniformingly and are fine with moving entire thing into CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/5cFVc/2/

Comment: Also if you want the images to be resized uniformingly, but cover entire possible space `background-size: contain;` is what you're after. Otherwise you can control the sizes of images in percentages `background-size: 50% 50%`, etc